# Get back information from combo box in .NET WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, type-conversion

My question is about combo boxes in WinForms. So assume we have a generic list and SingleItem class with a lot of fields. For example

```
class SingleItem{
    public int val1;
    public int val2;
    public string str;
    public override string ToString(){
        return str;
    }
};
List<SingleItem> listOfItems;
```

Assume, that we have **comboBox** variable. I'm adding items to comboBox this way

```
foreach(SingleItem item in listOfItems){
    comboBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And then, when user finished choosing an item, we need to get another field from chosen item. For example, i need something like this

```
comboBox.SelectedItem.val1; // where val1 is field of SingleItem class
```

That is the problem. I tried to Google this problem, but didn't find valuable answer for my question. I also tried to do a type conversion, but it fails. My current solution is searching selected value in list, but this solution have O(n) complexity and not good enough. Thanks

Comment: No, of course, this is just example, to show that i overrided ToString function to be able to add item to combo box.

Comment: What type conversion did you do? Because it should have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
class SingleItem
{
    public int val1 { get; set; }
    public int val2 { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return str;
    }

}

...

 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var obj = ((SingleItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).val1; 
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, it works. So i understood, that i have to write {get; set;} to get it work fine. Is'nt it?

Comment: Not really, but you do need to make those members public. Using getters and setters is just something I think is a better practice.

Comment: Thanks, this code was an example and not so good, i mean public there :) It's magic, i'v tried type conversion, but it fails :) thanks

Comment: @DavitPetrosyan I suggest that you mention it clearly in the future when you're posting pseudo-code. Better yet is to post code that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an Array instead of a itemlist, Arrays are easier to add in combobox

Here is code to get the value of selected item in combobox:

```
string str = (string)ComoBox.SelectedItem;
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that was not my problem. Under "getting object back" i mean all the fields of my object, not only "str" field (see example of class above). And i use List, coz standard arrays can't satisfy my needs.