# How can i access data from my function to use in another?

Tags: c#

I am building a GUI to DISM for our imaging tasks at the campus.
I have a function which uses WMI to grab my drive letters and index and put them in a combobox.

My problem is with the `combobox-SelectedIndexChanged`.
I want this to set a string var to whatever the index is of the selected drive in the combo box.

I need a way to reference the objects from my `getdrive()`

```
private void getdrive()
{

    WqlObjectQuery Query1 = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
    ManagementObjectSearcher Search1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query1);
    foreach (ManagementObject Object1 in Search1.Get()) {

        foreach (ManagementObject Object2 in Object1.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition")) {

            foreach (ManagementBaseObject Object3 in Object2.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk")) {

                comboBox5.Items.Add(new { Drive = Object1["Index"], Volume = Object3["Name"] }.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}


private void comboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // How do i get the following to work??
    sDISKPARTDRIVE = Object1["Index"];
}
```

The comboxbox results would display as:

```
{ Drive = 1, Volume = D: }

{ Drive = 0, Volume = C: }

{ Drive = 2, Volume = E: }

etc...
```

Comment: Just add a property to your class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get back information from combo box in .NET WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881291/get-back-information-from-combo-box-in-net-winforms)

Comment: In the line where you call comboBox5.items.Add(), The value being passed in is the data item for the combo box item - so you can get at that item from the "sender" parameter of the event handler... You'll need to cast it, But if you inspect it in the debugger you'll be able to work it out ...